# How to run angular4 test cases in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: angular, bitbucket-pipelines

I am integrating bitbucket pipeline for angular4, problem is that chrome browser is not opening in bitbucket pipeline console. actually, i want to know how to run test cases in bitbucket pipeline, for the angular4 build.

Answer (score 0):

By default the cli installs the karma-chrome-launcher. you could try installing a headless browser like phantomjs

```
npm i --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher
```

Then modify the plugins property of the karma.conf.js file, adding the PhantomJS plugin to the list. Also add PhantomJS to the browsers property.

```
plugins: [
    require( 'karma-jasmine' ),
    require( 'karma-chrome-launcher' ),
    require( 'karma-phantomjs-launcher' ),
    require( 'karma-remap-istanbul' ),
    require( 'angular-cli/plugins/karma' )
],

browsers: [ 'PhantomJS', 'Chrome' ],
```

Since you want a completely headless experience, you can remove Chrome from the browsers property, and remove the karma-chrome-launcher from the plugins array as well.